# Automate iOS application with amCharts element using Appium or Perfecto

Tags: selenium, appium, amcharts, appium-desktop, perfecto

Is it possible to automate iOS native application with **amCharts** elements using **Appium** or **Perfecto** ? [[Sample amChart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-time-line-pie-chart/?theme=none)]

Answer (score 0):

Perfecto is just mobile device cloud provider, where you can use Appium: so does not affect the possibility.

It may be tricky to parse amCharts for Appium just as it may be tricky to do so for XCUITest (that Appium use for iOS interactions). Since its [Objective C wrapper](https://www.amcharts.com/objective-c-wrapper-for-ios-osx/) chances are pretty good, but still you will be able to get **only numbers and element position in best case**.

I suggest to install [appium-desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop), start session with your app and make screen snapshot. If appium won't parse it, you may try do it directly in XCode with XCUITest and maybe you need to add some attributes for parsing via Appium

Comment: appium-desktop is not helping to inspect AmCharts element and entire chart is showing as a single element `(XCUIElementTypeOther name="AmChart")`

Comment: That was I said: you may need to add attributes in iOS app to store chart data (not sure if its possible), until then you are limited with 1 object

Comment: Could you please suggest any other mobile automation tools that support AmChart elements ?